# Открыть файл на редактирование в стороннем приложении iOS

Tags: ios, office, доступ

Всем добра! Столкнулся с проблемой при разработке на iOS. Необходимо открыть файл, который лежит в каталоге приложения, в другом приложении (рассматриваю пока только MS Office). Причем нужно не просто открыть, но и что-бы потом офис вернул измененный файл обратно без лишних действий пользователя.
**UIDocumentInteractionController** не подходит, так как для возврата документа нужно самому отправить его обратно в приложение.
Пробовал открыть документ как написано в документации к офису: https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn911482.aspx, но тогда офис не видит файл (что вполне логично, так как каждое приложение работает в песочнице).
Собственно вопрос: можно ли как-то дать доступ стороннему приложению к файлам, либо разместить их в каком-нибудь Shared Store, либо какой-нибудь еще способ отправить файл в приложение, но чтобы по завершении редактирования оно само этот файл вернуло?

Comment: Что бы вы не делали, принимающее приложение, должно уметь это обрабатывать. Другими словами, если офис принимает только ссылку на файл, никак вы это не поборете. Так что я бы предложил делать то, что написано в ссылке, приведенной в вашем вопросе, заливать файл куда то и передавать офису ссылку

Comment: Да, я это понимаю, но проблема в том, что Dropbox как то делает это :) То есть он именно дает доступ к своим файлам для MS Office, а потом кидает ссылку на них, что бы тот отредактировал их и вернул обратно... Причем это делается точно без сети, так как работает с отключенным интернетом :(((